# Pandas Python Script not holding respondents score in table

Tags: python, pandas, praw

There is a quiz script that gives a bonus to the fastest respondents and then 1 point for any correct answer in the timeframe. After a recent update for the newest pandas library the part that applies 1 point to all respondents no longer works. This is a partial segment of the code for it.

```
        if len(repHolder) > 0:

            repHolder.columns = ['name', 'points', 'time']

            repHolder = repHolder.sort_values('time').reset_index(drop=True)
            repHolder.loc[:, 'time'] = repHolder.loc[:, 'time'].apply(
                lambda x: (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x) + timedelta(hours=-4)).strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"))

            # Take the first response per participant
            minDate = repHolder.groupby('name').min()['time'].reset_index()
            repHolder = repHolder.merge(minDate)

            # For ties, score by time not by name
            timeHolder = repHolder.loc[repHolder['points'], ['time']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
            timeHolder['points'] = 0

            corHolder = 0
            for idx3, row in enumerate(timeHolder.iterrows()):
                if corHolder == 0:
                    timeHolder.loc[idx3, 'points'] = 1
                    corHolder = 1
                elif corHolder == 1:
                    timeHolder.loc[idx3, 'points'] = 1
                    corHolder = 2
                elif corHolder == 2:
                    timeHolder.loc[idx3, 'points'] = 1
                    corHolder = 3
                else:
                    timeHolder.loc[idx3, 'points'] = 1

            repHolder = repHolder.merge(timeHolder, on='time', how='left')
            repHolder['points'] = (repHolder['points_x'] * repHolder['points_y'])
            repHolder.loc[repHolder['points'].isnull(), 'points'] = 0

            print('scored winners')

            repHolder = repHolder.sort_values('points', ascending=False)

            repHolder['qTime'] = (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(qCom.created_utc) + timedelta(hours=-4)).strftime(
                "%I:%M:%S %p")
            repHolder['deltaTime'] = pd.to_datetime(repHolder['time']) - pd.to_datetime(repHolder['qTime'])

            repHolder['points'] = repHolder['points'] + repHolder[['deltaTime', 'points']]. \
                apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['deltaTime'].seconds <= 30) and (x['points'] == 1) else 0, axis=1)

            print(repHolder)

            winHolder = pd.concat([winHolder, repHolder])
```

Updated pandas code from this:

```
            if not reply.author == None and not reply.banned_by:
                repTab = pd.DataFrame([[reply.author.name, gottem, reply.created_utc]])
                repHolder = repHolder.append(repTab)
```

to this:

```
            if not reply.author == None and not reply.banned_by:
                repTab = pd.DataFrame([[reply.author.name, gottem, reply.created_utc]])
                repHolder = pd.concat([repTab])
```

post update which got the code to run again but then the code stopped holding all the responses

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` method has been deprecated in pandas 2. The alternative `pd.concat` function requires a list of dataframes to concatenate, so you need to pass in the original dataframe.

Try:

```
if not reply.author == None and not reply.banned_by:
                repTab = pd.DataFrame([[reply.author.name, gottem, reply.created_utc]])
                repHolder = pd.concat([repHolder, repTab])
```